# Windows, same mountpoint for two different Drives

Tags: windows, backup, mount

I want to use two different HDD's to making backups. The backups I make with acronis.

So I need a path for the Backup Destination, what have always to be the same, when Drive A is attached and when Drive B is attached.

I mount the Drive in a Folder: C:\backup, but when I set this mountpoint in Drive A, I can't set it also in Drive B.

Is there a way to mount each drive in the same mountpoint or have I to make more Backup plans with different Backup Destinations?

I'm using Win7, 64bit on the PC where the Backup starts.

**EDIT:**

When connecting Drive A, then Drive B is disconnected, Drive a should be mounted on c:\hdd. When Connecting Drive B, Drive A is disconnected, Drive B should be mounted on c:\hdd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only native solution I can think of is writing a VBscript.

Another solution is to script the mounting of drives using Diskpart. Use `diskpart /s filename.txt` and you can use diskpart to create a script file for you.

Use this page to find the commands.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490893.aspx

Then you can either go the hard route and write a script/batchfile to switch between the disks, or you can go the easy way and write two separate scripts and backup plans with Acronis. Just tell it to run a set of commands before the backup.